# How to create Web Application in Apache Netbeans 10?

Tags: web, netbeans-10

Just I've downloaded Netbeans 10. While creating new project, I'm not getting option 'Web Application'.

How to do it?
Is there GUI design builder for web applications in Apache Netbeans 10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike some earlier NetBeans releases such as 8.2, Apache NetBeans 10.0 does not support web development by default, and that is why you do not see an option for **Java Web** under the **Categories** listed within the **Project Wizard**. See [What's Happened to My Favorite NetBeans Plugins?](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-happened-to-my) for additional background information.

However, web development can still be performed using Apache NetBeans 10.0. You just need to install some plugins first:

- Go to **Tools > Plugins** and select the **Available Plugins** tab.
- Ensure that the entries are sorted in ascending **Category** order. Click the **Category** column header to do that if necessary.
- Scroll down and locate the entries for the **Category** named **Java Web and EE**.
- Under the **Install** column check all of those entries:

  [image: installPlugins]
- Click the **Install** button to install those checked **Java Web and EE** plugins.
- Follow the instruction for the **Installer** wizard. The requested plugins will be downloaded and installed, and you will be invited to click **Finish** to restart NetBeans.
- After the restart select **File > New Project...**. There should be new entries in the **Categories** list named **Java Web** and **Java EE**, allowing you to create web and EE applications:

  [image: installPlugins2]

Troubleshooting:

- If there are no entries for **Java Web and EE** on the **Available Plugins** tab then update your question with a screen shot of **Tools > Plugins > Settings**.
- If the plugins appear to install correctly but **Java Web** and **Java EE** are still not available under the **Project Wizard** after a restart then update your question with:

  - A screen shot of **Tools > Plugins > Installed**, with the **User Installed Plugins** entry selected.
  - The recent content of the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**).

Comment: Warning - could not install some modules: Nashorn Integration - No module providing the capability com.oracle.js.parser.implementation could be found. 15 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.

[ Disable Modules and Continue ]
[ Exit ]

Comment: @अक्षयपरूळेकर I have no idea about that, although someone else has raised a bug report for it on NetBeans: [NETBEANS-1806](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1806). If it is still a problem you could create a new question, but I don't think it is related to the issue you raised above.

Comment: I got that issue too 'Warning - could not install...'

Comment: Finally I returned back to Netbeans 8.0.1 for Web Projects

Comment: @अक्षयपरूळेकर [1] That's a shame. I think you might at least try regressing to NetBeans 8.2 instead of NetBeans 8.0.1, since it will contain many bug fixes from earlier releases of NetBeans 8.x, and will be more stable. [2] Another approach you could try is to [download and install Apache NetBeans 11.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html) instead of Apache NetBeans 10.0. [3] Note that you can safely install and use different major versions of NetBeans concurrently, such as NetBeans 8.x and NetBeans 11.0.

Comment: @skomisa Netbeans 8.2 had problem of starting Tomcat Server. I tried a lot to solve it. I reinstalled it but problem didn't solved. Even I tried different versions of tomcat... but still didn't worked! That's why finally I did have to install Netbeans 8.0.1 and Tomcat started successfully.

Answer (score 6):

If you're not seeing the Java Web and EE categories, you need to go into Settings and make sure Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal is checked like in the image below.

[image: Enable Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal]