# Missing Java Web in Netbeans 10

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications, java-web-start

I'm using Netbeans 10. While creating a new project, I'm not getting an option 'Web Application'. In Netbeans 8.2 version is it there. But Netbeans 10 I can't find Web App.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is migrating to Apache and the web part is not migrated yet. But you can still use it with NetBeans 10. skomisa gave a nice answer how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087962/875083