# Apache netbeans IDE 10.0 installed with JEE Support but annotations still as error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, annotations, netbeans-10

I have installed Apache Netbeans IDE 10.0 on Linux Mint, and followed this recommendation to activate JEE support ( https://superuser.com/questions/1404517/how-to-enable-java-ee-in-apache-netbeans-ide-10 ). I have restarted Netbeans and JEE annotations are marked as errors *"Incompatible types : Path cannot be converted to annotation"*. This happens with all Java EE annotations, and I don't know how to solve this.

I have tried to do clean and build but still the same. Here is a screen shot of some sample errors:

[image: JavaEEerrors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problems because the solution you followed for the accepted answer to the superuser question [How to Enable Java EE in Apache Netbeans IDE 10](https://superuser.com/q/1404517/863146) is wrong.

That answer advises you to use an Update Center to download some plugins used in NetBeans 8.2. That was an appropriate workaround on NetBeans 9, but wrong for NetBeans 10 since the appropriate plugins you need are already available (on the **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins** tab), and you just need to install them. You don't need to obtain any plugins from any Update Center for Java EE, and doing so will probably be harmful.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087962/2985643) to the SO question [How to create Web Application in Apache Netbeans 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54079789/2985643) for details on which of the available plugins need to be installed.

Notes:

- I think you should first reinstall NetBeans 10 if possible, to start with a clean environment.
- If that is not possible you should first uninstall those NetBeans 8.2 plugins you added to NetBeans 10, and then restart NetBeans.
- Although the SO answer I linked to is for a slightly different question, the solution applies equally to your problem.
- Although not related to your question at all, you might consider also [upgrading to Apache NetBeans to version 11.1](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb111/nb111.html) if that is possible. If you did that you would still follow exactly the same process detailed in the linked answer for installing the Java EE plugins.

Comment: Hi . I just installed the last version ( apache netbeans 11.1) and everything works as a charm . Thanks a lot .